# Find and extract a number from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a requirement to find and extract a number contained within a string.

For example, from these strings:

```
string test = "1 test"
string test1 = " 1 test"
string test2 = "test 99"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Might the number be negative? If so, how would "Hello - how are you? -30" be handled?

Comment: Hi John, No negative numbers in the data

Comment: Decimal numbers like `1.5`? Exponential notation like `1.5E45`?

Comment: Similar (but not identical): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561273/parse-an-integer-from-a-string-with-trailing-garbage

Comment: your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844461/return-only-digits-0-9-from-a-string/844479#844479

Comment: Why is no answer accepted here?

Comment: check this gist https://gist.github.com/anirugu/780a1f1319bfe39f47f6efa0197985c8

Answer (score 104, accepted):

go through the string and use `Char.IsDigit`

```
string a = "str123";
string b = string.Empty;
int val;

for (int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
        b += a[i];
}

if (b.Length>0)
    val = int.Parse(b);
```

Comment: @Thomas: That code does not work, it results with `b == "System.Linq.Enumerable.."`.  Correct (and even simpler) would be `b = String.Join("", a.Where(char.IsDigit))`

Comment: Good point, that'll teach me not to test the code I write in comment! You can also make a string from a char array using the `new string(char[])` constructor.

Comment: Regex does a much better job.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft  Why not make your comment a proper answer so I can vote it up  :-)

Comment: NOTE: If the string contains multiple numbers, this answer will run them all together into a single number. E.g. "a12bcd345" results in "12345". (Which may be desirable or not, depending on the goal.) This is different than the top-voted Regex solution, which would return "12" for the case above. This matters for cases like phone numbers "555-111-2222".

Comment: this is a very cumbersome and low-level way and not recommended when you can use the built-in Regex support.

Answer (score 746):

`\d+` is the regex for an integer number. So

```
//System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

returns a string containing the **first occurrence** of a number in `subjectString`.

`Int32.Parse(resultString)` will then give you the number.

Comment: to support negative numbers you could use `Regex.Match(subjectString, @"-?\d+").Value` instead

Comment: @JonList: OP stated in his comment above that he's not looking for negative numbers, but yes, that would be possible if desired.

Comment: This answer ist not complete (in C#). It is only getting the first number in the string. You have to itarate over the matches: resultString = string.Join(string.Empty, Regex.Matches(subjectString, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));

Comment: @Markus: The question states "I need to extract ***a*** number contained within a string", and all the examples show a single number being present in the string. Iterating over a single item is not useful.

Comment: @Markus: For something like v2.0.1, your answer works (returns 201), whereas the above answer does not (returns just 2). It seems more complete to me. Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker: hi, if I have sting like this 
"(14,347,198,538.033000)",
how to get the value, what I should put instead of \d+

Comment: @TimPietzcker: "14347198538.033" , and is there any link you recommend to understand how RegularExpressions.Regex work? thanks

Comment: @ayman: Oh, the commas are thousands separators? That will require a much more complex regex - which should be dealt with in a separate question. An excellent starting point is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which also contains sections on .NET's regex engine.

Comment: simple, non regex answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844461/return-only-digits-0-9-from-a-string/844479#844479

Comment: No this answer is WRONG. Can't believe all the upvotes. It doesn't work for phone numbers "(717) 555-1212" returns "717"

Comment: @DavidSopko: The question is about extracting a single integer number from a string, not about parsing phone numbers (there are enough questions about that topic on StackOverflow)...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker if the answer is correct then the question is wrong because the SOLUTION is extract the FIRST number, and the QUESTION is 'extract numbers' <-- plural. You see in programming these seemingly slight differences in semantics have a major impact on the outcome.

Comment: @DavidSopko: "I have a requirement to find and extract *a number* contained within a string"...

Comment: Question changed to match the solution

Comment: @DavidSopko: What are you talking about? The original question asked for a way to extract a single number from a string, both in the title and in the question body. Subsequent edits to the question (a year after my answer and later) by people other than the original author changed the title to "numbers". If anything, that faulty edit should be rolled back.

Comment: This does not work if you try to parse a decimal or thousand separators.

Answer (score 286):

Here's how I cleanse phone numbers to get the digits only:

```
string numericPhone = new String(phone.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice solution for integers! Be aware that this won't work if you're trying to parse a decimal number because the decimal point is not a digit.

Comment: You can also replace the string construction with a `Concat` if you prefer: `string.Concat(phone.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())`.

Answer (score 47):

use regular expression ...

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
Match m = re.Match("test 66");

if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("RegEx found " + m.Value + " at position " + m.Index.ToString()));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a string containing a number!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works event without space, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/47ebfb01c087).

Answer (score 42):

What I use to get Phone Numbers without any punctuation...

```
var phone = "(787) 763-6511";

string.Join("", phone.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit));

// result: 7877636511
```

Answer (score 30):

Regex.Split can extract numbers from strings. You get all the numbers that are found in a string.

```
string input = "There are 4 numbers in this string: 40, 30, and 10.";
// Split on one or more non-digit characters.
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
foreach (string value in numbers)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
    int i = int.Parse(value);
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Number: 4
>   Number: 40
>   Number: 30
>   Number: 10

Comment: Prefix ZERO values are not extracting. Ex.0001234. O/p: 1234

Answer (score 20):

if the number has a decimal points, you can use below

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("anything 876.8 anything", @"\d+\.*\d*").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("anything 876 anything", @"\d+\.*\d*").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("$876435", @"\d+\.*\d*").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("$876.435", @"\d+\.*\d*").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

results :

> "anything 876.8 anything"  ==>   876.8
>
> "anything 876 anything"  ==>   876
>
> "$876435"  ==>   876435
>
> "$876.435"  ==>   876.435

Sample :  https://dotnetfiddle.net/IrtqVt

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I am using C# and VS2017 and was trying to figure out how do I find the value. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: FYI this also extracts MULTIPLE values, perfect solution

Answer (score 17):

Here's a `Linq` version:

```
string s = "123iuow45ss";
var getNumbers = (from t in s
                  where char.IsDigit(t)
                  select t).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(new string(getNumbers));
```

Comment: what about simply `"123iuow45ss".AsEnumerable().Where(char.IsDigit)` ?

Comment: I just don't like `from t .. select t` redundancy, but anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 16):

Another simple solution using Regex
You should need to use this

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

and the code is

```
string var = "Hello3453232wor705Ld";
string mystr = Regex.Replace(var, @"\d", "");
string mynumber = Regex.Replace(var, @"\D", "");
Console.WriteLine(mystr);
Console.WriteLine(mynumber);
```

Comment: It wasn't exactly what the question was asking, but it was exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 14):

Here is another simple solution using `Linq` which extracts only the numeric values from a string.

```
var numbers = string.Concat(stringInput.Where(char.IsNumber));
```

Example:

```
var numbers = string.Concat("(787) 763-6511".Where(char.IsNumber));
```

Gives: "7877636511"

Answer (score 13):

You can also try this

```
string.Join(null,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(expr, "[^\\d]"));
```

Comment: nice but if you have spaces between the numbers in the original string then it will give you 1 large concatenated string with both numbers joined (no space)

Answer (score 12):

Here is another `Linq` approach which extracts the first number out of a string.

```
string input = "123 foo 456";
int result = 0;
bool success = int.TryParse(new string(input
                     .SkipWhile(x => !char.IsDigit(x))
                     .TakeWhile(x => char.IsDigit(x))
                     .ToArray()), out result);
```

Examples:

```
string input = "123 foo 456"; // 123
string input = "foo 456";     // 456
string input = "123 foo";     // 123
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using `String` property like below:

```
 return new String(input.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

which gives only number from string.

Answer (score 12):

```
 string input = "Hello 20, I am 30 and he is 40";
 var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the best answer which gave me what I wanted, which is array of multiple numbers within string. If only it could ignore commas in numbers (thousand separator) then that would be perfect!  :-)

Answer (score 11):

Just use a RegEx to match the string, then convert:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(test , @"(\d+)");
if (match.Success) {
   return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var match=Regex.Match(@"a99b",@"\d+");
if(match.Success)
{
    int val;
    if(int.TryParse(match.Value,out val))
    {
        //val is set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For those who want **decimal** number from a string with **Regex** in **TWO** line:

```
decimal result = 0;
decimal.TryParse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value, out result);
```

Same thing applys to **float**, **long**, etc...

Answer (score 7):

The question doesn't explicitly state that you just want the characters 0 to 9 but it wouldn't be a stretch to believe that is true from your example set and comments. So here is the code that does that.

```
        string digitsOnly = String.Empty;
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            // Do not use IsDigit as it will include more than the characters 0 through to 9
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') digitsOnly += c;
        }
```

Why you don't want to use Char.IsDigit() - Numbers include characters such as fractions, subscripts, superscripts, Roman numerals, currency numerators, encircled numbers, and script-specific digits.

Answer (score 6):

```
var outputString = String.Join("", inputString.Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

Get all numbers in the string. 
So if you use for examaple '1 plus 2' it will get '12'.

Answer (score 5):

Extension method to get all **positive** numbers contained in a string:

```
    public static List<long> Numbers(this string str)
    {
        var nums = new List<long>();
        var start = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (start < 0 && Char.IsDigit(str[i]))
            {
                start = i;
            }
            else if (start >= 0 && !Char.IsDigit(str[i]))
            {
                nums.Add(long.Parse(str.Substring(start, i - start)));
                start = -1;
            }
        }
        if (start >= 0)
            nums.Add(long.Parse(str.Substring(start, str.Length - start)));
        return nums;
    }
```

If you want negative numbers as well simply modify this code to handle the minus sign (`-`)

Given this input:

```
"I was born in 1989, 27 years ago from now (2016)"
```

The resulting numbers list will be:

```
[1989, 27, 2016]
```

Answer (score 5):

An interesting approach is provided [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fb0c6b7-9c81-4ff9-a5bb-b9926c7a3911/how-can-i-extract-numbers-only-from-a-string?forum=regexp) by Ahmad Mageed, uses Regex and `StringBuilder` to extract the integers in the order in which they appear in the string.

An example using `Regex.Split` based on the post by Ahmad Mageed is as follows:

```
var dateText = "MARCH-14-Tue";
string splitPattern = @"[^\d]";
string[] result = Regex.Split(dateText, splitPattern);
var finalresult = string.Join("", result.Where(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e)));
int DayDateInt = 0;

int.TryParse(finalresult, out DayDateInt);
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used this one-liner to pull all numbers from any string.

```
var phoneNumber = "(555)123-4567";
var numsOnly = string.Join("", new Regex("[0-9]").Matches(phoneNumber)); // 5551234567
```

Comment: Strangely for me var resolves to a string with the following content "System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection"  Maybe adifferent C# version ?

Comment: could also use @"\d+" for the regex.  Note you'll need the @ in front to allow the use of the \

Comment: @sirclesam Yep totally, I just default to `[0-9]` because its more readable in my opinion. But that's totally just flavor!

Answer (score 3):

Did the reverse of one of the answers to this question:
[How to remove numbers from string using Regex.Replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657282/how-to-remove-numbers-from-string-in-regex-replace)

```
// Pull out only the numbers from the string using LINQ

var numbersFromString = new String(input.Where(x => x >= '0' && x <= '9').ToArray());

var numericVal = Int32.Parse(numbersFromString);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  string verificationCode ="dmdsnjds5344gfgk65585";
            string code = "";
            Regex r1 = new Regex("\\d+");
          Match m1 = r1.Match(verificationCode);
           while (m1.Success)
            {
                code += m1.Value;
                m1 = m1.NextMatch();
            }
```

Comment: This Code is used to find all integer value in a string.

Comment: It would be better to add some description directly into the answer than to post it separately as a comment. Comments are not always immediately visible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Algorithm

```
    //Fast, C Language friendly
    public static int GetNumber(string Text)
    {
        int val = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = Text[i];
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                val *= 10;
                //(ASCII code reference)
                val += c - 48;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static string GetdigitFromString(string str)
    {
        char[] refArray = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
        char[] inputArray = str.ToCharArray();
        string ext = string.Empty;
        foreach (char item in inputArray)
        {
            if (refArray.Contains(item))
            {
                ext += item.ToString();
            }
        }
        return ext;
    }
```

Comment: Tried other approaches, like regex, etc.. but this was the simplest to understand!

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

```
string var = "Hello345wor705Ld";
string alpha = string.Empty;
string numer = string.Empty;
foreach (char str in var)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(str))
        numer += str.ToString();
    else
        alpha += str.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine("String is: " + alpha);
Console.WriteLine("Numeric character is: " + numer);
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Regex as `\d+`

`\d` matches digits in the given string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "kg g L000145.50\r\n";
        char theCharacter = '.';
        var getNumbers = (from t in s
                          where char.IsDigit(t) || t.Equals(theCharacter)
                          select t).ToArray();
        var _str = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in getNumbers)
        {
            _str += item.ToString();
        }
        double _dou = Convert.ToDouble(_str);
        MessageBox.Show(_dou.ToString("#,##0.00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @tim-pietzcker [answer from above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string/4734164#4734164), the following will work for `PowerShell`.

```
PS C:\> $str = '1 test'
PS C:\> [regex]::match($str,'\d+').value
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using StringBuilder is slightly more performent than string concatanation in a loop. If you are dealing with large strings, it is considerably more performant.

```
    public static string getOnlyNumbers(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
                stringBuilder.Append(input[i]);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Note: above example function only works for positive numbers

Answer (score -3):

Based on the last sample I created a method:

```
private string GetNumberFromString(string sLongString, int iLimitNumbers)
{
    string sReturn = "NA";
    int iNumbersCounter = 0;
    int iCharCounter = 0; 

    string sAlphaChars = string.Empty;
    string sNumbers = string.Empty;
    foreach (char str in sLongString)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(str))
        {
            sNumbers += str.ToString();
            iNumbersCounter++;
            if (iNumbersCounter == iLimitNumbers)
            {
                return sReturn = sNumbers;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sAlphaChars += str.ToString();
            iCharCounter++;
            // reset the counter 
            iNumbersCounter = 0; 
        }
    }
    return sReturn;
}
```