# Find number in string

Tags: c#

How to find number(int, float) in a string (fast method)?
For example: "Question 1" and "Question 2.1".
I need that in variable would be only number.
Thanks.

Comment: One of your questions is about regular expressions. theres your answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# find and extract number from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/c-find-and-extract-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this `([0-9]\.*)*[0-9]` regex to get it. you can test any regex [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

**Edit**

this sample code in `C#`

```
Regex regexpattern = new Regex(@"(([0-9]\.*)*[0-9])");
String test = @"Question 1 and Question 2.1.3";
foreach (Match match in regexpattern.Matches(test))
{
    String language = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reqular Expressions. To search numbers try this:

```
var r = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("Question 2.1", "\d+");
```

Comment: This will return 1 and 2 but not 1.2

Answer (score 1):

There's always the good ol' regular expressions! It wouldn't give you a float for "2.1" though, but I'm not sure that's a good idea since there's always the possibility of "2.1.4" or even "2a". Might be best to store a vector of numbers for each item.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.