# How to search for a word in a string and then get the numbers after this word?

Tags: c#, .net, string, search

Like:

```
"Name: Daniel --- Phone Number: 3128623432 --- Age: 12 --- Occupation: Student"
```

How to get what is after "Age"? I would only like the numbers. (his age)

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions :)

Comment: Use String.IndexOf http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/c-sharp-find-and-extract-number-from-a-string find inspiration here

Comment: Have you same format in all cases? field:value(empty space)(three hyphens)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use RegEx:

```
^.+Age\: ([0-9]+).+$
```

First grouping will return the age, see [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/ADPRtesYY1) or [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/aunCzEVdNC).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a full code with following concept:

```
string strAge;
string myString = "Name: Daniel --- Phone Number: 3128623432 --- Age: 12 --- Occupation: Student";
int posString = myString.IndexOf("Age: ");

if (posString >0)
{
  strAge = myString.Substring(posString);
}
```

Robust way of doing is to get some Regular Expressions :) though...

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have age in this format `Age: value`

```
string st = "Name: Daniel --- Phone Number: 3128623432 --- Age: 12 --- Occupation: Student";
//Following Expression finds a match for a number value followed by `Age:`
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match mt = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(st, @"Age\: \d+");
int age=0; string ans = "";
if(mt.ToString().Length>0)
{
     ans = mt.ToString().Split(' ')[1]);
     age = Convert.ToInt32(ans);
     MessageBox.Show("Age = " + age);
}
else
     MessageBox.Show("No Value found for age");
```

MessgeBox show you, your string value (if found)..

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have data, which could be easily represented as dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
var s = "Name: Daniel --- Phone Number: 3128623432 --- Age: 12 --- Occupation: Student";
var dictionary = s.Split(new string[] { "---" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                  .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                  .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
```

Now you can get any value from your input string:

```
string occupation = dictionary["Occupation"];
int age = Int32.Parse(dictionary["Age"]);
```

Comment: This is a good and possible solution but maybe the OP doen't have the data ready in variables (getting info from third-party e.g.).

Comment: It does not make any difference where string comes from. As a final result we will have a variable referencing string data :)