# get measurement value only from string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string which gives the measurement followed the units in either cm, m or inches.

For example :

The number could be 112cm, 1.12m, 45inches or 45in.

I would like to extract only the number part of the string. Any idea how to use the units as the delimiters to extract the number ?

While I am at it, I would like to ignore the case of the units.

Thanks

Comment: you have a collection of such strings?

Comment: No, just one string. It is not a list

Comment: if so, you don't need `LINQ`.

Comment: just prototype var buff = new List<char>();
for(i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
  char ch = str[i];
  if(ch >= '0'  && ch <= '9')
   buff = 
}

Comment: If you still have any ambiguity, you can have a look at my solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the solution you have proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
string numberMatch = Regex.Match(measurement, @"\d+\.?\d*").Value;
```

**EDIT**

Furthermore, converting this to a double is trivial:

```
double result;
if (double.TryParse(number, out result))
{
    // Yeiiii I've got myself a double ...
}
```

Comment: his number can also be decimal, this is not enough.

Comment: Ya That's right. That was my query too. It does not handle Double does it ?

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in That was not in your question (maybe you should specify it), nevertheless, you can check my edit and get the idea how to handle the different types.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am sorry I have mentioned in my question 1.12m and extract only the number. Is it misleading ? But the regex pattern `@"^\d+"` ignore decimal right and gives you only the integer part.

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in you're right, my regex skills are a bit rusty, sorry :) I've edited it a bit. Needs testing though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Split` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Something like:

```
var units = new[] {"cm", "inches", "in", "m"};
var splitnumber = mynumberstring.Split(units, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var number = Convert.ToInt32(splitnumber[0]);
```

Comment: The OP should better go for `Regex`.

Comment: Yes, there's a million of different posibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex this can help you out:

```
(?i)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=c?m|in(?:ch(?:es)?)?)
```

#### Break up:

```
 (?i)                 = ignores characters case // specify it in C#, live do not have it
 \d+(\.\d+)?          = supports numbers like 2, 2.25 etc
 (?=c?m|in(ch(es)?)?) = positive lookahead, check units after the number if they are 
                        m, cm,in,inch,inches, it allows otherwise it is not.
 ?:                   = specifies that the group will not capture
 ?                    = specifies the preceding character or group is optional
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/gmW15FRNvK)

**EDIT**

Sample code:

```
MatchCollection mcol = Regex.Matches(sampleStr,@"(?i)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=c?m|in(?:ch(?:es)?)?)")

foreach(Match m in mcol)
{
    Debug.Print(m.ToString());   // see output window
}
```

Comment: I like this approach the best because it can be applied against strings which may contain other unrelated text.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'd try to replace with "" every character that is not number or ".":

```
//s is the string you need to convert
string tmp=s;
foreach (char c in s.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (!(c >= '0' && c <= '9') && !(c =='.'))
                    tmp = tmp.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
            }
s=tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expression \d+ to find an integer number.

```
resultString = Regex.Match(measurementunit , @"\d+").Value;
```

Comment: This is an answer which i would highly recommend as its the easiest to understand and the cleanest

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement that you use the unit as the delimiter? If not, you could extract the number using regex (see [Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/c-sharp-find-and-extract-number-from-a-string)).

Comment: No, That was not a requirement. I thought that was the effective way of doing it. I will check your link. Thanks