# c# - Extract first integer from a string

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following 2 string, how can I get the first integer that occurs from each one *without using regex*:

```
"Result Set 25: 171 companies"  =>  get 25
"Other Text 22 : 140 companies"  =>  get 22
```

Comment: Why the non-regex requirement?

Comment: Personal preference but fine I'll just leave a comment to make it clear. Go for it. If there's a concise no-regex solution will accept that

Comment: We will not "go for it". Why don't you give it a shot instead?

Comment: I do not know regex that is why the preference not to use it

Comment: You can learn how to use regexes. The complicated ones are... complicated. But sometimes they can be really easy to use. Are you also going to be reluctant to use LINQ?

Comment: The regex solution is clear and concise: `string result = Regex.Match(input, "[0-9]+").Value; // returns "" if no match`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use linq to find the first sequence of digits

```
var digits = input.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c))
    .TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit)
    .ToArray();

var str = new string(digits);
int i = int.Parse(str);
```

You might want to check the resulting string is non-empty before you try parse it to check there were any digits in the input.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Char.IsDigit` will also return true for Unicode digits like ९, which `int.Parse` will reject, so it would be better to explicitly check for `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = new string(input.SkipWhile(x=>!char.IsDigit(x))
                             .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
//You can apply int.Parse() on the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how efficient it is, but it's the best I can make without RegEX.

```
string a = "Result Set 25: 171 companies";
string b = string.Empty;
int val;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
        b += a[i];
    else if (b.Length != 0)
        break;
}
if (b.Length > 0)
val = int.Parse(b);
```

Based on @LexRema at [Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/c-sharp-find-and-extract-number-from-a-string)