# How to Know whether Variable Contains a integers or Strings?

Tags: c#

I just want to know, whether a variable contains a positive integer value.

Currently I am doing:

```
int APPOeeVersion = 
    Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OEEVersion"]);
```

Here i just want to know whether APPOeeVersion Contains Int value or not. If not Need to show a error message as it is invalid format. Please help me out i have checked with several forums but not find exact solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert String to Int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: not a duplicate of that^^

Comment: Regular expression is more suitable for checking "a positive integer value"

Answer (score 8):

Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), It will not raise an exception in case of failure and would give you `bool` value back if parsing was successful/unsuccessful.

```
string str = "1234";
int APPOeeVersion;
if (int.TryParse(str, out APPOeeVersion))
{
    //parsing successful
}
else
{
    //not an integer
}
```

If parsing is successful you will get the value of parsed string in your `out` parameter.

For checking a positive number and parsing you can have the check like:

```
if (int.TryParse(str, out APPOeeVersion) && APPOeeVersion > 0)
```

Comment: Technically, `int.TryParse` will return `true` for a negative value, which might not be what the OP intended.

Comment: @rae1n, Missed the positive number part of the question, but edited the answer with an extra check.

Comment: `uint.TryParse` would also do this, no ? (of course, APPOeeVersion should also be an uint)

Answer (score 1):

`int.TryParse` would be the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

```
int APPOeeVersion;
if(!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OEEVersion"], out APPOeeVersion) || APPOeeVersion < 0){
   //throw error
}

//use variable APPOeeVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test for a *positive* integer, then you might need to use `uint.TryParse` since `int.TryParse` will allow negative values.

```
uint appoEeVersion;
var oeeVersionValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OEEVersion"];
if(!uint.TryParse(OEEVersionValue , out appoEeVersion))
{
     // Error, not a positive integer
}
else
{
     // Success, user value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your wording. Do you mean the variable **is** an integer or **contains** an integer? 
If the former, then the solutions posted will work fine.

Are you guaranteed that the variable will only ever be an integer with no decimal notation (eg: 2 vs 2.0)? If not, you might need to use [decimal.parse instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Integer parsing will fail on the other decimal values since they are not valid integers.

```
            Decimal APPOeeVersion;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(input,out APPOeeVersion))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully parse: {0} to {1}", input, APPOeeVersion);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse {0}", input);

            }
            Console.Write("\nEnter a number to test: ");
```

Then then use additional logic to ensure that the result is positive. 
If you want to know whether it contains an integer, then a regular expression like the ones found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/c-sharp-find-and-extract-number-from-a-string) will work.

Maybe I'm just dumb or overthinking this, but it seems like you have to give a few more constraints