# Extract first numeric chars from a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, linq-to-entities

I need to extract first numeric value set from a string. Here ([Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string)), I have found a RegEx way to do that. But, in my case I have a LINQ query from where I need to do the same logic.

**Here is my exisiting Logic**

```
bool Isbn = db.BibContents.Any(ad => ad.NormValue == ISBN);  // I need to do the numeric split logic into the db column NormValue
```

**Note**

I cannot loop here to get values first and compare in the loop. Because, I have huge number of records in DB and NormValue Column is nvarchar(max) typed.

Any help to this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably handle that in a stored procedure...

Comment: Yup, if you need database regex support (or equivalent functionality), that's a situation where stored procedures might be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Isbn = db.BibContents.Any(ad => GetDigits(ad.NormValue) == ISBN);

public string GetDigits(string text) {
     return string.Join("",text.AsEnumerable().Where(char.IsDigit));
}
```

How about that?

Comment: Getting this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetDigits(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Updated the method with string signature instead of int signature

Comment: I used string signatured method only and got that above error.

Comment: The problem is about the LINQ to Entities doest not work with user defined functions to convert it to store expression.

Comment: In that case you have a few options, use linq to entities to create you own sql query, where you do the logic on the sql side. Or query all the data inside a list and then iterate over your list to retrieve the correct data. Since you say you have quite an extensive set of data the first option might be the better. (You could also create a stored procedure on your db.)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about you parse your result to string? I don't know that much about LINQ but I would parse the result into String and use regex.