# C# String Get Between in a HTML Code

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a string variable with this content:

`(<b><a href="#post9736461" title="Show">Permalink</a></b>)`

How can I get the `9736461` in an extra variable? The String is always the same, just the numbers changes.

**EDIT:**

I tried:

```
Tag = Regex.Replace(Tag, @"(<b><a href=\"#post");
Tag = Regex.Replace(Tag, @"" title=\"Show\">Permalink</a></b>)");
```

Comment: Use a proper library for Html parsing. See [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for example

Comment: @Steve You don't need a HTML parsing library for this snippet.  It's pure XML in syntax so could be handled with XML and XPath.

Comment: If this small string is invariant except for the the digits part, I don't see any point in using a parsing library.

Comment: All you need to do is grab the digits? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do:

```
string input = "(<b><a href=\"#post9736461\" title=\"Show\">Permalink</a></b>)";
string value = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=#post)\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=#post)(\d+)
```

will get you the numbers in `\1`

Comment: No need for backreferencing if you use a zero-width lookbehind. Also I doubt this is very clear to someone with little regex understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(#post\d+)""", "$1");

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(#post\d+)»
   Match the characters “#post” literally «#post»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
```