# How do i parse the number only from item and put the number in int variable?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            item = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }
```

When doing SelectedIndex so in this case item = "0"
Then i'm doing:

```
CreateMainDirectory(int.Parse(item));
```

So in CreateMaindirectory the number is 0.
But the first index/item in the comboBox is:

```
"Reduced by: 10"
```

So i want to parse the number 10. So in CreateMainDirectory should be the number 10.

And if i'm doing:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            item = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

Then item is: "Reduced by: 10"

How can i parse the number 10 if i'm using SelectedIndex and/or SelectedItem ?

Comment: You want to get only integer part in a string? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item = new string(item.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Or:

```
item = item.Split().Last();
```

If the number is always at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
numberString = Regex.Match(mainString, @"\d+").Value;
```

[\d+ is regex for numbers ]
thn Int32.Parse(numberString ) will give you the actual number