# Extract number from end of string

Tags: c#

I have some strings like "pan1", "pan2", and "pan20" etc. I need to extract number. I use it:

```
char ch = s[(s.Length) - 1];
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(ch));
```

But in case of, for example, "pan20" the result is not correct 0.

Comment: Will all of your strings always have 'pan' in them? If so, just remove 'pan'.

Comment: Yes, if 'pan' is consistent, use Substring to get the remaining text (after these three characters) and convert this to a number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: This question is not the same as the linked question "Find and extract numbers from a string". Here it's about the end of a string. The linked answer will find all integers in a string, forcing you to iterate through the Regex' results. @SamiKuhmonen gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Index Approach

if you know where is the starting index of the number then simply you can do this :

```
string str = "pan20";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(3));
```

Note that "3" is the starting index of the number.

---

### Fixed Prefix Approach

try to remove "pan" from the string; like this

```
string str = "pan20";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(str.Replace("pan", ""));
```

---

### Regular Expression Approach

use regular expression only when string contains undetermined text inside

```
string str = "pan20";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example regular expressions, for example `[0-9]+$` to get the numbers in the end. See the [Regex class in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).