# Scan string for numbers

Tags: c#

I have a string with words and numbers.
How can i find the last number (the number of digits are unknown) and isolate it?
Till now I used the Substring method, but the location of the number in the text, and also the length of the number, are unknown.

Thanks!

Comment: I advise you too look up here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4734164/2524304

Comment: @user3057504 Can you please clarify, do you want the last _digit_ or the last _number_ that appears in the string?

Comment: Thaks for all the answers! I need the whole number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var number = Regex.Match(input, @"(.*\D|^)(\d+)").Groups[2].Value;
```

Or a slightly different solution with a little bit of Linq thrown in for good measure:

```
var number = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Last().Value;
```

And here's a solution using a plain old `for` loop; no Linq or regex required:

```
int start = 0, end = 0;
for (var i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (char.IsDigit(input[i]))
    {
        end = i + 1;
        while (i >= 0 && char.IsDigit(input[i])) i--;
        start = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
var number = input.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this combination of efficient string methods and readable LINQ:

```
string text = "Foo 1234 Test Bah344 ....";
int index = text.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
if(index >= 0)
{
    string until = text.Substring(0, index + 1);
    var digits = until.Reverse().TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).Reverse();
    string lastNumber = new string(digits.ToArray());  // 344
}
```

Here's a one-and-a-half-liner which is not as efficient:

```
var lastDigits = text.Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c))
    .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).Reverse();
string lastNumber = lastDigits.Any() ? new string(lastDigits.ToArray()) : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the more explicit way:

```
var lastNumberIndex = yourString
        .LastIndexOfAny(new[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'});
```

Comment: `"0123456789".ToCharArray()` is it better? :)

Comment: you have to cycle through your whole array at every char

Comment: But doesn't give the whole number _"How can i find the last number "_

Comment: @FSou1 even more resource cost. +1 Tim, Google digit vs number pls.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var res = Regex.Matches("kadlkfmg 57 dklfmgladg 89 dfdd", @"\d+");
var lastMatch = res.Cast<Match>().LastOrDefault();
if(lastMatch != null)
{
    var nr = lastMatch.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply start from the end and search for the first integer value you can find. In my opinion, this is the most performant way to do this.

For the last digit:

```
string s = "randomstringwithnumbers1234567890";
for (int i = s.Length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (int.tryParse(s[i], out n) //or use if (char.IsDigit(s[i]))
      return s[i];
}
```

For the last number:

```
string s = "randomstringwithnumbers1234567890";
string b = "";
for (int i = s.Length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) //or use if (char.IsDigit(s[i]))
{
   if (int.tryParse(s[i], out n)
      b =+ s[i];
   else if (b.Length() != 0)
      return b;
}
```

Comment: `s[i].GetType()` will return char.

Comment: Aaah yes u were right. Changed to tryparse(). Its late here :)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question sufficiently. As the number that should be returned is `1234567890`, not `0`.

Comment: I am cycling through every character in the string, so the first one is "0".

Comment: @flol, I misunderstood the OP's question. I reversed my vote. Sorry for that!!

Comment: Thank you. In my opinion, this should be the most performant way. What do you think?

Comment: @flol Well, it'll work. I'm not sure about _most_ performant. For example, is your code any more/less performant than @terrybozzio's answer: `var mychar2 = testing.Last(c => char.IsDigit(c))`? But it will work, so I voted it up. :)

Comment: Hmm. I just read it. I do not know what is going under the hood at `IsDigit()`. The Lambda looks elegant :)

Comment: @flol, I think the OP mean the last number, not simply the last digit. Anyhow, `char.IsDigit` simply tests a character to see, if in the machine's local culture, the current character is a digit character. E.g. for en-US, 0, 1, 2, etc. are characters which are digits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I added a second version to check for the last number.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the last digit in the string(both examples):

```
string testing = "SomeTextWith3Various45Numbers345InIt";
var mychar = testing.Reverse().First(c => char.IsDigit(c));
var mychar2 = testing.Last(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

Edit:

To Get the Last number(whole) this will do:

```
var mychar3 = new string(testing.Reverse()
                                .SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c))
                                .TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c))
                                .Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: OP said last "number"