# Show one column from multiple drop down list when select from the it

Tags: c#, dropdownlistfor

I am working on web app with data base (SQL server). I made my multiple drop down list and now what I need is when I select one value from it to show only first column.

Something like this:

```
id ,      Text

31231 dadsadsa

32131 dsadsads

54345 dasdadsd

53455 trretrer
```

When I select the first row `31231 dadsadsa`, I want to appear only the id of it (`31231`).

I use this to bind these two columns

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    id = dt.Rows[i]["first_c"].ToString();
    name = dt.Rows[i]["second_c"].ToString();
    newName = id + " ---- " + name;
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(newName, id));
}
```

I hope you guys understand me.

Comment: Maybe get the int from the DropDownList value? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: what is the problem with your code? what do you see with it and what do you want to see?

Comment: When i choose from drop down list one value, in the drop down list appears the whole row(newName value), instead only id value. I am searching for something like DisplayMember in Combo.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField ="id";
DropDownList1.DataTextField="newName";
```

Comment: i think that this 2 answers are same like my solution. I tried them but it doesnt work. Again, when i choose from drop down list one value, in the drop down box appears the whole row(newName value), instead only id value

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SelectListItem> DropDownList1 = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    id = dt.Rows[i]["first_c"].ToString();
    name = dt.Rows[i]["second_c"].ToString();
    newName = id + " ---- " + name;

    DropDownList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = id, Value = newName}); 
}
```

Comment: i think that this 2 answers are same like my solution. I tried them but it doesnt work. Again, when i choose from drop down list one value, in the drop down box appears the whole row(newName value), instead only id value