# Decorating numbers inside the string with the thousand separator

Tags: c#, regex, string

A have a string that contains one ore more number. The numbers are normally integers, but also decimal could be expected at some point. I looking for a solution that adds the thousand separator(. or ,) to all numbers inside the string.

For example

1. 100000 -> ?100,000?
2. ?100000?50000 -> ?100,000?50,000
3. X10000.5? -> X100,00.5?

Any idea?

Comment: What the `?` in the above means?

Comment: What is the point of question marks?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: ? represents just a normal character that has to be preserved in the result. For example for "TestX10000FOO" i expect to get "TestX10,000FOO".

Comment: So you have some strings with randomly nested numbers in them?

Comment: Yes. That is right. A string can contain multiple numerical values in random places. Basically, I have to find all numbers inside the string and decorate them with thousand separator.

Comment: Thean take one of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string) and combine the output with `.ToString("N")`

Comment: khlr Unfortunately "ToString(XX" works only, with a "well formated" single number. In order to use .ToString( withe the format parameter you need a number.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky solution in pure regex is to replace all occurences of

```
(?<=\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)
```

with `,$1`. This is, of course, very limited, as it only adds one separator per number, and also adds separators after a comma. [See regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/lL8aJ1/1)

---

A far cleaner solution is to search for numbers using a regex such as `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, convert each match to a number, and re-insert the formatted number into the text.

(You'll have to forgive me for not including any code, but I haven't coded in C# in ages.)