# Regex that returns a list

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that I am looking up that can have two possible values:

1. `stuff 1`
2. `grouped stuff 1-3`

I am not very familiar with using regex, but I know it can be very powerful when used correctly. So forgive me if this question sounds ridiculous in anyway. I was wondering if it would be possible to have some sort of regex code that would only leave the numbers of my string (for example in this case `1` and `1-3`) but perhaps if it were the example of `1-3` I could just return the `1` and `3` separately to pass into a function to get the in between.

I hope I am making sense. It is hard to put what I am looking for into words. If anyone needs any further clarification I would be more than happy to answer questions/edit my own question.

Comment: Are there any other numbers in your values?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: @Rawing - yes the numbers may change

Comment: @scapegoat17: I didn't mean it like that - what I'm asking is, can `stuff` or `grouped stuff` contain numbers? For example `grouped 7 stuff 1-3`?

Comment: @Rawing - Oh sorry. no it would only be in formats above. With the numbers varying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a list of numbers in string y, use the following:

```
var listOfNumbers = Regex.Matches(y, @"\d+")
                           .OfType<Match>()
                           .Select(m => m.Value)
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fully possible, but best done with two separate Regexes, say `SingleRegex` and `RangedRegex` - then check for one or the other, and pass into a function when the result is `RangeRegex`.

As long as you're checking for "numbers in a specific place" then extra numbers won't confuse your algorythm. There are also several Regex Testers out there, a simple google Search weill give you an interface to check for various syntax and matches.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to loop through all of the numbers in the string?

Here's one way you can loop throw each match in a regular expression.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
        string s = "grouped stuff 1-3";

        Match m = r.Match(s);

        while(m.Success) 
        {
            string matchText = m.Groups[0].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(matchText);
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }   
    }

}
```

This outputs

> 1
>
> 3