# How to extract multiple numbers from the string?

Tags: c#

I want to to extract multiple numbers from a string. The string may be like below:

```
hello:123.11,good:456,bye:789.78
```

And I want to get 3 numbers(including **both integer and float numbers**): 123.11, 456, 789.78 by C#.

Updated: including float number, not all integer.

How?
Thanks!

Comment: first split first by semi-colon,
then split each by colon,
and you may get the numbers

Comment: Duplicate of: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Matches` method of the `Regex` class with regex to get all the occurrence of the digits.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var subjectString = "hello:123,good:456,bye:789";
        var result = Regex.Matches(subjectString, @"[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+");
        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
}
```

**[DOT NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IarqYj)**

Comment: Thank you! I update my post, the numbers include float ones, so your code works only for integer number. Any update?

Comment: @TomXue Updated my answer just need to replace regex in old version.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string digitsOnly = String.Empty;
            string s = "2323jh213j21h3j2k19hk";
           List<int> MyNumbers = new List<int>();
            foreach (char c in s)
            {

                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') digitsOnly += c;
                else
                {
                     int NumberToSave;

                      bool IsIntValue = Int32.TryParse(digitsOnly, out NumberToSave);

                      if (IsIntValue)
                      {
                         MyNumbers.Add(Convert.ToInt16(digitsOnly));
                      }



                    digitsOnly=String.Empty;
                }
            }

            foreach (int element in MyNumbers)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine(element);
                }


        }
    }
```