# How do I get two numbers between two words (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string "Building1Floor2" and it's always in that format, how do I cleanly get the building number (e.g. 1) and floor number. I'm thinking I need a regex, but not entirely sure that's the best way. I could just use the index if the format stays the same, but if I have have a high floor number e.g. 100 it will break.

P.S. I'm using C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and extract a number from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex like this:

```
Building(\d+)Floor(\d+)
```

Comment: This will match the entire thing, what's the point?

Comment: Yes, and it will put the two numbers into capturing groups which you can then use.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry I forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

Regex would be an ok option here if "Building" and "Floor" could change.  e.g.: "Floor1Room23"

You could use `"[A-Za-z]+([0-9]{1,})[A-Za-z]+([0-9]{1,})"`

With those groupings, $1 would now be the Building number, and $2 would be Floor.

If "Building" and "Floor" never changed, however, then regex might be overkill.. you could use a string split

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the "F" and substring on that.

```
int first = str.IndexOf("F") ;

String building = str.substring(1, first);
```