# Extracting certain data from a string?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to extract an integer from a position in a string? Each string will have the word "documents" after it (e.g. "There are 22 documents").

Comment: will there be more than 1 integer in the string?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Even googling will give you pretty fast answers.

Comment: `IndexOf` function `SubString` function Come on @JW111 this is 2016 and everyone should know how to initiate a simple google search in all due respect..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and extract a number from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string) this was the first result for my google of "find integer in string c#": https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=find+integer+in+string+c%23

Comment: Use a regex, that would be the safest way

Comment: Try regex if it is only integer in string. `Regex.Match(str, @"\d");` Or use following if your number is placed on a specific `index` . `Regex.Match(str.Substring(index), @"^\d");`

Comment: Do you want to remove the integers from the string, or do you want to copy this specific data and use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

here is something you can use and play around with. If your data always contains the words `There is  documents` then you have `There is 22 documents` you will return the integer(s)

```
string asplitStr = "There is 22 documents";
var aspltLsts = asplitStr.Split(new[] { "There is", "documents" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

A better solution using `Linq` you can do the following as well

```
string asplitStr = "There is 22 documents";
string resultStr = new String(asplitStr.
     Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```

> Returns " 22 "

Comment: Looking for `int` using regex will be better than this.

Comment: Yes I know but the OP doesn't understand Regex because they didn't know about the basic `IndexOf`