# string to int,causing app to stop

Tags: android, string, int

```
final EditText ed7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Recycleweight);
final EditText ed8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nonweight);
final EditText ed11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalweight);

recy_wt=ed7.getText().toString();
nonrec_wt=ed8.getText().toString();
total_wt=ed11.getText().toString();

int rec = Integer.parseInt(recy_wt);
int nrec = Integer.parseInt(nonrec_wt);
ed11.setText(String.valueOf(rec + nrec));
```

The input I am giving is,ed7=10kg and ed8=20kg,and it will be displayed in ed11
as 30kg,but the app is unfortunately stopping.
If I am not writing 'kg',it is correctly displaying the totalwt.
But I want to display 'kg' in the answer.

Comment: What programming language is that C# or Java?

Comment: with string as "kg" how can you parse it in integer for that use substring or replace and remove kg from string then it will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and extract a number from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Comment: programming language is java

Answer (score 1):

There is already a solution here (can't flag as duplicate)
[Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Extract the digit part from the string and then parse it to an integer

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
String regexp = "/^[0-9]+kg$/g"; //It accepts only '<number><kg>' format
int weight = 0;
if (recy_wt.matches(regexp) && nonrec_wt.matches(regex)) {
    //It's valid input
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(recy_wt);
    weight = Integer.parseInt(scan.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(nonrec_wt);
    weight += Integer.parseInt(scan.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"));
}

ed11.setText(String.valueOf(weight + "Kg"));
```

Comment: It is giving 0kg as answer. and 'scan' is causing duplicate,after I changed it to 'scan1' still its not working.

Comment: With what inputs, you get that result?

Comment: with, 20kg and 10kg

Comment: I think our `if` condition is not executing. put break point inside `if` and check

Comment: even when I gave only numbers like,20and 30,still the ans is 0kg

Comment: ya, the above `regex` condition only checks with `<number><kg>` format and returns `0kg` if not. if you mention what are the possible inputs, and possible `units` (ex: kg, km), we can build another regex

Comment: or else i'll post one more answer. if it works fine, reply me back

Answer (score 0):

If the only possible unit is `kg`, then try like this

```
final EditText ed7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Recycleweight);
final EditText ed8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nonweight);
final EditText ed11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalweight);

int weight = 0;

recy_wt=ed7.getText().toString();
nonrec_wt=ed8.getText().toString();

recy_wt = recy_wt.replace("kg","");
nonrec_wt = nonrec_wt.replace("kg","");

weight += Integer.parseInt(recy_wt) + Integer.parseInt(nonrec_wt);

ed11.setText(weight + "kg");
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:-

```
recy_wt=ed7.getText().toString();
nonrec_wt=ed8.getText().toString();

String n=recy_wt.replace("kg","");
String n1=nonrec_wt.replace("kg","");

weight += Integer.parseInt(n) + Integer.parseInt(n1);
ed11.setText(weight + "kg");
```

storing the replaced one in a string and then converting to int will help.

Comment: what's the difference between this and my second answer?

Comment: There I was still getting 0kg as the answer

Comment: there i forgot to assign the new string(i.e after str.replace("kg", "")) to variables. but the logic is same. now i updated the answer

Comment: Yes.Thank you.I have put one more ques,need a help in that.

Comment: I'll try to help you on that too. btw accept an answer which helped you to solve your problem