# How can I extract an integer value from a list containing a text string?

Tags: c#

I have the following list:

```
    List<string> scores = new List<string>
    {
        "1 point",
        "2 points",
        "5 points",
        "10 points",
        "15 points",
        "20 points",
        "25 points",
        "30 points",
        "40 points",
        "50 points"
    };
```

My code GUI selects one of these and returns a value from 0 to 9.

How can I convert return a number from 1 to 50 given the 0-9 number?

Comment: How does your GUI decide that one of these values should return 0-9? Based on its index?

Comment: what do you mean 0 to 9? Is it an index value or the value of your list itself?

Comment: Duplicates hopefully cover both question in title (extract number) and body (index of element or element by index). If you are asking about something else please [edit] to clarify. (Probably mapping 0-9 range to 1-50 numbers should be done with `Dictionary<int, int>` altogether....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *My code GUI selects one of these* you mean a selection is made from this list and you would like to know its `index` you could try.

```
var testInput = "10 points";
var scores = new List<string>
{
    "1 point",
    "2 points",
    "5 points",
    "10 points",
    "15 points",
    "20 points",
    "25 points",
    "30 points",
    "40 points",
    "50 points"
}; 
var index = scores.IndexOf(testInput); //<- Returns 3
```

If you mean your value is `3` and you want to turn that to `10 points` you can do the following.

```
var index = 3;
var scores = new List<string>
{
    "1 point",
    "2 points",
    "5 points",
    "10 points",
    "15 points",
    "20 points",
    "25 points",
    "30 points",
    "40 points",
    "50 points"
}; 
var score = scores[index]; //<- Returns 10 points
```

Comment: couldn't have done it better!

Answer (score 3):

As [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4734164/6741868) suggests, Regex can be helpful here:

Given an integer (between 0 and 9, do the checking beforehand to ensure it is in that range):

```
resultString = Regex.Match(scores[x], @"\d+").Value;
var points = Int32.Parse(resultString);
```

P.S. You'll need to have `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`