# Retrieving Numeric value before a decimal in a string value

Tags: c#

I am working on a routine in C#

I have a list of alphanumeric sheet numbers that I would like to retrieve the numbers before the decimal to use in my routine.

```
FP10.01-->10
M1.01-->1
PP8.01-->8
```

If possible, how can something like this be achieved as either a string or integer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string check this, may have an idea

Comment: Try putting the each alphanumeric string in a list, and convert all possible items (the numbers) to integers. Then read the adjacent integers and output them in one string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex("([0-9]+)[.]");

string s = "FP10.01";

var result = Convert.ToInt32(r.Match(s).Groups[1].ToString()); //10
```

Comment: the regex matches the '.' and r.Match(s).Groups[1] is the decimal group instead of the number group

Answer (score 0):

To accumulate the resulting elements into a list, you can do something like:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>(){ "FP10.01","M1.01", "PP8.01"};
List<int> resultSet = 
     myList.Select(e => 
             Regex.Replace(e.Substring(0, e.IndexOf('.')), @"[^\d]", string.Empty))
           .Select(int.Parse)
           .ToList();
```

This will take each element in `myList` and in turn, take a substring of each element from index `0` until before the `.` and then replace all the non-numeric data with `string.Empty` and then finally parse the string element into an `int` and store it into a list.

another variant would be:

```
List<int> resultSet =
               myList.Select(e => e.Substring(0, e.IndexOf('.')))
                     .Select(e => string.Join(string.Empty, e.Where(char.IsDigit)))
                     .Select(int.Parse)
                     .ToList();
```

or if you want the elements to be strings then you could do:

```
List<string> resultSet =
               myList.Select(e => e.Substring(0, e.IndexOf('.')))
                     .Select(e => string.Join(string.Empty, e.Where(char.IsDigit)))                  
                     .ToList();
```

To retrieve a single element of type `string` then you can create a helper function as such:

```
public static string GetValueBeforeDot(string input){
     return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('.'))
                 .Where(char.IsDigit)
                 .Aggregate(string.Empty, (e, a) => e + a);
}
```

To retrieve a single element of type `int` then the helper function should be:

```
public static int GetValueBeforeDot(string input){
       return int.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('.'))
                   .Where(char.IsDigit)
                        .Aggregate(string.Empty, (e, a) => e + a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string input = "FP10.01";
        string[] _input = input.Split('.');
        string num = find(_input[0]);

        public string find(string input)
        {
            char[] _input = input.ToArray();
            int number;
            string result = null;
            foreach (var item in _input)
            {                
                if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out number) == true)
                {
                    result = result + number;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach removes alphabet characters by replacing them with an empty string.  Splitting on the '.' character will leave you with a two element array consisting of numbers at index 0 and after decimal values at index 1.

```
string input = "FP10.01";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"([A-Za-z]+)", string.Empty).Split('.');
var beforeDecimalNumbers = result[0]; // 10
var afterDecimalNumbers = result[1];  // 01
```