# Get a number and string from string

Tags: c#, string

I have a kinda simple problem, but I want to solve it in the best way possible. Basically, I have a string in this kind of format: `<some letters><some numbers>`, i.e. `q1` or `qwe12`. What I want to do is get two strings from that (then I can convert the number part to an integer, or not, whatever). The first one being the "string part" of the given string, so i.e. `qwe` and the second one would be the "number part", so `12`. And there won't be a situation where the numbers and letters are being mixed up, like `qw1e2`.

Of course, I know, that I can use a `StringBuilder` and then go with a `for` loop and check every character if it is a digit or a letter. Easy. But I think it is not a really clear solution, so I am asking you is there a way, a built-in method or something like this, to do this in 1-3 lines? Or just without using a loop?

Comment: Search for Regex to separate numeric characters from alphabetic characters

Comment: You can use a lambda expression with take while not numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with named groups to identify the different parts of the string you are interested in.

For example:

```
string input = "qew123";
var match = Regex.Match(input, "(?<letters>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<numbers>[0-9]+)");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["letters"]);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["numbers"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Linq* as an alternative to *regular expressions*:

```
string source = "qwe12";

string letters = string.Concat(source.TakeWhile(c => c < '0' || c > '9'));
string digits = string.Concat(source.SkipWhile(c => c < '0' || c > '9'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Where()` extension method from `System.Linq` library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where), to filter only chars that are digit (number), and convert the resulting `IEnumerable` that contains all the digits to an array of chars, that can be used to create a new `string`:

```
string source = "qwe12";
string stringPart = new string(source.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
string numberPart = new string(source.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
MessageBox.Show($"String part: '{stringPart}', Number part: '{numberPart}'");
```

Source:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669520/8133067

Answer (score 0):

if possible add a space between the letters and numbers (q 3, zet 64 etc.) and use string.split
otherwise, use the for loop, it isn't that hard

Answer (score 0):

You can test as part of an aggregation:

```
var z = "qwe12345";
var b = z.Aggregate(new []{"", ""}, (acc, s) => {
  if (Char.IsDigit(s)) {
    acc[1] += s;
  } else {
    acc[0] += s;
  }
  return acc;
});
Assert.Equal(new [] {"qwe", "12345"}, b);
```