# Parsing a number out from a string

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have something like this:
Cat= "I cost £3,000"

And some are like this:
AnotherCat= "that other cat is just £10 more expensive than mine £2990

I want to parse out just 3000 from cat and 2990 from Another Cat

Comment: And what will happen with 10 from AnotherCat? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string) similar question. Maybe it'll help you.

Comment: @LeviTheOne I don't necessarily need 10 and to add to the question  sometimes I might just need 10 and not 2990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is much more complicated then parse number from string. If you just want to extract all number from string you can use next regex:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(stringValue, @"\d+");
```

but if you want to to understand, where is price of something, but not a count of cats, for example, it is related to Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning.