# How can I extract 5 digit numbers from a large string?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used a timer to run through a `string`, I have used a `while` too but I am wondering is there a faster way. I have string that contains date serial number, the date is always after the text `d|`

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string caldata = textBox6.Text;
    textBox7.Text = caldata.Length.ToString();

    if (caldata.Substring(0, 2) == "d|")
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Found date" + caldata.Substring(2, 5));
        listBox1.Items.Add(caldata.Substring(2, 5));

        textBox6.Text = caldata.Remove(0, 7);
        caldata = textBox6.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox6.Text = caldata.Remove(0, 1);
        caldata = textBox6.Text;
    }


    if (caldata.Length < 4)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

My string that contains the data looks like the attached.

Comment: Hard to see a question.  You make it faster by not using a timer.

Comment: http://agiofin.com/data.txt

Comment: tried using while but its still takes too long ...

Comment: Please don't downvote, he is a new bee. Also what make you use timer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Comment: To see if it is doing something ...lol ... I tried while but it looks like it hangs and takes minutes and then it responds so it takes to long to start doing its job

Comment: *My string that contains the data looks like the attached.* you seemed to of forgotten to finish this?

Comment: @OxleyPilot where's the string? Post the question in the question itself. What are you searching for? Righ now people have to guess what you want from the code and a missing input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, your problem could be solved with careful debugging and stepping through the code.

Anyway, below is my suggestion:

You could use regular expressions: `(?<=d\|)\d{5}`

Explanation:

`(?<=d\|)` - positive lookbeihnd: assert what preceds is `d\|`

`\d{5}` - match 5 digits

Code sample

```
  string caldata = "";
  MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(caldata, @"(?<=d\|)\d{5}");
  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
    string txt = match.Value;
    // ... do smoething with text
  }
```

Comment: Why the positive look behind? `\d{5}` should do it fine?

Comment: @Liam To assert what preceds is desired `d|`, then take (match) five numbers

Comment: I've just seen the `d|` requirement!

Comment: Now I have learnt something, Finding the data is much faster, I was looking into regex now, but this has put me on the correct path. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove and Substring are pretty slow string operations, if you want to extract data from a string you should try to find only that and not remove the irrelevant data around it.

Regex seems to be the way go here, in this case "(?!d\|)\d{5}" should be the fastest.

So your code would look like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(caldata, @"(?!d\|)\d{5}");
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
  listbox1.Items.Add(m.Value);
}
```