# How to extract integer values from inside a string

Tags: c#, string, split, integer

I run the PowerShell command to get total RAM capacity using C# and it returns this value. `@{TotalPhysicalMemory= 17856325}`. I wrote a code to get the only integer value. This is the code.

```cs
string ramSize = "@{TotalPhysicalMemory= 17856325}";
string ramValue = ramSize.Split('=')[1].Split('}')[0].Trim().ToString();
```

This code returns the integer value. But I want to know are there any ways to get this integer value easily?

Comment: It's pretty easy to pick up using a _regular expression_. Look up the `\d` character class element

Comment: i try to do, but i cant figure out how use this. can you explai? @Flydog57

Comment: The point of PowerShell commands is that they return *objects*. In fact, this string you're trying to parse is a representation of an object that has a `TotalPhysicalMemory` property. You should request that property directly. If you're dealing with the string rendering of that object, you lost the advantage well before this point.

Comment: Get a search tool (Google, Bing), and search for my italicized term ("Regular Expression") maybe add `\d` to the search, and C# for good luck.  My search turned up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference, a very good link.  Then in the left hand pain, there's a link to the "Overview" topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions.  Between the two, you should be able to figure things out.  Pulling a number from a string is one of the basic RegEx examples.  Enjoy learning

Comment: One thing to note is that if you are looking at total RAM for a computer, you probably don't want to use an `int`.  Use a `long` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple regex to extract the digits in the string will do it.

```
var ram = new Regex(@"\d+").Match(ramSize).Value;
```

you can also add System.Management and directly get the size by

```
            var ram =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                    "SELECT TotalPhysicalMemory FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
                .Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().First()
                .Properties.OfType<PropertyData>().First().Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Regex** to get the value.

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/dDzpx3/1)

> First capturing group
>
> > `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]) and
> > `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times

Hence, `match.Groups[1].Value` will get the value from group `(\d+)` as mentioned above.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpression;

string ramSize = "@{TotalPhysicalMemory= 17856325}";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\@{TotalPhysicalMemory= (\d+)}");
var match = regex.Match(str);
var ramValue = match.Groups[1].Value;

Console.WriteLine("Value: " + ramValue);
```

Output

> Value: 17856325

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iCDhDr)

Answer (score 3):

To only get the first Number in a string you can easily do this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions 
string ramValue = Regex.Match(ramSize, @"\d+").Value;
```

To get all numbers in a string you could use Linq:

```
using System.Linq
string ramValue = ramSize.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()
```

also have a look over here:

[Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)