# C# Sorting a list of strings that contains numbers 2

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

I need to sort the List by the numbers in the string while keeping the name with the string. Here is an example of what I have in mind:

**An unordered List**:

```
BA05
R01
BA03
MTA008
MTA002
R07
```

**Ordered List:**

```
R01
MTA002
BA03
BA05
R07
MTA008
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you already have.

Comment: `var sorted = data.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value));`

Comment: @RFE_Petr What if? Like "NODIGIT", "2 M4NY D1G1T5" ?

Comment: What if an element in list does not have numeric value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var unorderedList = new List<string>(){"BA05", "R01", "BA03", "MTA008", "MTA002", "R07"};

var orderedList = unorderedList
    .Select(input => new
    {
        text = input,
        number = int.Parse(Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value)
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.number)
    .Select(x => x.text).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
So you can do this:
    - Create another list for the numbers that are in the strings
    - Take the numbers out of the strings using .Substring(int startindex, int length), and add them to the number-list
    - Perform a simple sorting algorithm by the number-list and exchange the elements in both lists with the same index
*/
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(); //Create a list for the numbers from the strings

//not important
FileStream FS = new FileStream("list.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS);
while(!SR.EndOfStream) { strings.Add(SR.ReadLine()); }
//not important

foreach (string s in strings)
{
    int index = 0, result = 0;
    do //Take the numbers out from the string (BA05 --> 05 --> (convert to int) 5)
    {
        int.TryParse(s.Substring(index, s.Length - index), out result);
        if (result == 0) index++;
    }
    while (result == 0);
    numbers.Add(int.Parse(s.Substring(index, s.Length - index)));
}
Console.WriteLine("Unsorted:");
foreach (string s in strings) Console.WriteLine(s);
//Perform a simple sorting algorithm (f.e.: a bubble sort)
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) //Exchange both elements with the same index in both list
        {
            int tempInt = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
            numbers[j + 1] = tempInt;
            string tempStr = strings[j];
            strings[j] = strings[j + 1];
            strings[j + 1] = tempStr;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\nSorted:");
foreach (string s in strings) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

> Unsorted:
> BA05
> R01
> BA03
> MTA008
> MTA002
> R07
>
> Sorted:
> R01
> MTA002
> BA03
> BA05
> R07
> MTA008