# Sorting a given string - What is wrong with my IF Contains block?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, contains

Super new to C# apologize upfront. My goal is to sort a given string. Each word in the string will contain a single number. This number is the position the word should have in the result. Numbers can be from 1 to 9. So 1 will be the first word (not 0).

My plan of attack is to split the string, having one variable of int data-type (int lookingForNum) and the other variable turning that into a String data-type(string stringLookingForNum), then for each loop over the array looking to see if any elements contain `string stringLookingForNum`, if they do I add it to an emptry string variable, lastly add 1 to int variable `lookingForNum`. My issue seems to be with the  if statement with the Contains method. It will not trigger the way I currently have it written. Hard coding in  `if (word.Contains("1"))` will trigger that code block but running it as written below will not trigger the if statement.**Please can anyone tell my WHY!?!?** I console.log `stringLookingForNum` and it is for sure a string data type "1"

This noobie would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
string testA = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a";  //-->  "Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
string[] arrayTestA = testA.Split(' ');
string finalString = string.Empty;

int lookingForNum = 1; //Int32
foreach (string word in arrayTestA){
    string stringLookingForNum = lookingForNum.ToString(); 
    
    //Don't understand why Contains is not working as expected here)
    if (word.Contains(stringLookingForNum)){
        finalString = finalString + $"{word} ";
        
    }
    lookingForNum++;
    
}
```

Comment: Your numbers never line up.  Your are looking for "1" on the first word, which is "is2".  You are looking for "2" in the second word, which is "Thi1s", etc, etc.  Maybe comment out the `lookingForNum++;` line to get some result.  Learn to debug to step through this code line by line would help you see the problem.

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which in turn will help you write better code.

Answer (score 2):

you need this - look for the string with 1, the look for the string with 2 etc. Thats not what you are doing

you look at the first string and see if it contains one

then look at the second one and see if it contains 2
....

```
 int lookingForNum = 1;
 while(true){ // till the end
     string stringLookingForNum = lookingForNum.ToString(); 
     bool found = false;
     foreach (string word in arrayTestA){
        
        if (word.Contains(stringLookingForNum)){
           finalString = finalString + $"{word} ";
           found = true;
           break;
        }
      }
      if(!found) break;
  
   lookingForNum++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort you should simply use `OrderBy`, and since you need to sort by number inside a word - just [Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

```
string testA = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a";
var result = testA.Split().OrderBy(word =>
    Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(word, @"\d+").Value));
    
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Comment: This looks pro to me! I was about to recommend using Regex but found this. Well, the OP was learning and new to c#, 1st one seems helpful but over the time, something like this is helpful.