# Can't get DependencyProperty to work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I wrote a small attached property called "IsValid" for the WPF TextBox, like so:

```
public enum InputTypes
{
    Any,

    Integer,

    Double,

    Float
}

/// <summary>
/// This attached property can be used to validate input for <see cref="TextBox"/>. 
/// </summary>
public class IsValid : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Input",
        typeof(InputTypes),
        typeof(IsValid),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(InputTypes.Any, onInput));

    public static InputTypes GetInput(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (InputTypes)d.GetValue(InputProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInput(DependencyObject d, InputTypes value)
    {
        d.SetValue(InputProperty, value);
    }

    private static void onInput(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)d;
        var value = (InputTypes)e.NewValue;
        switch (value)
        {
            case InputTypes.Any:
                textBox.PreviewTextInput -= validateInput;
                textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= validateKeyDown;
                break;

            default:
                textBox.PreviewTextInput += validateInput;
                textBox.PreviewKeyDown += validateKeyDown;
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void validateInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        // enforce numeric input when configured ...
        var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
        var inputTypes = (InputTypes) textBox.GetValue(InputProperty);
        foreach (var c in e.Text)
        {
            switch (inputTypes)
            {
                case InputTypes.Integer:
                    if (!char.IsDigit(c))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    break;

                case InputTypes.Double:
                case InputTypes.Float:
                    if (!char.IsNumber(c))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void validateKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // block [SPACE] when numeric input is expected ...
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var inputTypes = (InputTypes)textBox.GetValue(InputProperty);
        if (inputTypes != InputTypes.Any && e.Key == Key.Space)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

End here's how I've used it:

```
<Window x:Class="Spike.Wpf.Controls.TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:values="clr-namespace:Spike.Wpf.Controls.Input;assembly=Spike.Wpf.Controls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox values:IsValid.Input="Double" />
</Grid>
```

After the initialization (of the `DependencyProperty`) none of the methods in `IsValid` gets called however. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you verify that the property is getting assigned to `InputTypes.Double` and not string `"Double"`?

Comment: I would take another look at your handling of your input.  I don't think your checks are doing what you think they are. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228532/difference-between-char-isdigit-and-char-isnumber-in-c

Comment: @Rachel: Yes, having resolved the issue (see the answer) I can very that I did get the expected value. WPF takes care of the parsing.
@Brent: Indeed, you're absolutely right. I also realized my solution wasn't adequate. Just specifying "double" or "integer" wasn't enough. I also need to specify how many decimals are allowed along with the usual minimums and maximums. So, I decided to go ahead and build a couple of `MarkupExtension` classes. The resulting syntax is very pleasant. I'm quite new to WPF but so far I have to say it's very powerful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier you probably got an error telling you that `IsValid` needs to derive from `DependecyObject`, so you added that, you should have asked yourself why that is. The answer is right here:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...
```

You try to register a normal property for objects on type `IsValid`, change it to `RegisterAttached` and it should work. (I would also remove the inheritance and make `IsValid` a static class)

Comment: Duh! I feel like a git. Thanks! :O)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the core of the problem was trivial (see accepted answer): I needed to call `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(...)` (as opposed to `DependencyProperty.Register(...)`.

Just wanted to share the result. I decided to scrap the use of a simple `enum` to specify input type and decided to use markup extensions instead.

The attached property implementation now looks like this:

```
public static class IsValid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Input",
        typeof(IsValidInputExtension),
        typeof(IsValid),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(onInput));

    public static IsValidInputExtension GetInput(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (IsValidInputExtension)d.GetValue(InputProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInput(DependencyObject d, IsValidInputExtension value)
    {
        d.SetValue(InputProperty, value);
    }

    private static void onInput(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)d;
        var value = (IsValidInputExtension)e.NewValue;
        if (value == null)
        {
            textBox.PreviewTextInput -= validateInput;
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= validateKeyDown;
            return;
        }
        textBox.PreviewTextInput += validateInput;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown += validateKeyDown;
    }

    private static void validateInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        // dispatch validation to specified markup class ...
        var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
        var markup = (IsValidInputExtension)textBox.GetValue(InputProperty);
        markup.ValidateInput(sender, e);
    }

    private static void validateKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // dispatch validation to specified markup class ...
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var markup = (IsValidInputExtension)textBox.GetValue(InputProperty);
        markup.ValidateKeyDown(sender, e);
    }
}
```

And here's part of the markup extension classes:

```
public abstract class IsValidInputExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    internal abstract void ValidateInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e);
    internal abstract void ValidateKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e);
}

public class NumericExtension : IsValidInputExtension
{
    public double Minimum { get; set; }

    public double Maximum { get; set; }

    public uint Decimals { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    internal override void ValidateInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
        if (isDecimalSeparator(e.Text) && Decimals == 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        // todo: honor Minimum and Maximum ...
    }

    private static bool isDecimalSeparator(string s)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator == s;
    }

    internal override void ValidateKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // block [SPACE] when numeric input is expected ...
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
    }
}

public class StringExtension : IsValidInputExtension
{
    public double MaximumLength { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    internal override void ValidateInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        // (nop)
    }

    internal override void ValidateKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // todo: honor MaximumLength here
    }
}
```

The end result, in XAML, is quite nice and easy to read...

```
<TextBox v:IsValid.Input="{v:Numeric Minimum=0, Maximum=99, Decimals=0}" />
```

It all seems to work as I hoped. Thanks for all input

Cheers

/Jonas