# how to check if the character is an integer

Tags: c#

I am looking for a function that can check the character if it is a integer and do something is so.

```
char a = '1';

if (Function(a))
{
  do something
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should consider if you need "interger" (as sequence of digits - there are couple characters like this), "digit" (0-9 in multiple languages) or "a number" (1/2,...)

Answer (score 41):

Use [System.Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx) method

Comment: +1 to both IsDigit and IsNumber. Note that neither guarantees that character is "integer" because IsDigit simply means it is on digit of potentially longer integer, IsNumber could be float (i.e. 1/2).

Comment: IsDigit covers 0-9 and equivalents in other character sets, and is always an integer for a single character (for a longer string, use Integer.TryParse). IsNumber returns true for 0-9 as well as for some more interesting Unicode characters in the "Number, Other" and "Number, Letter" groups like ½ (that's 1 character) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm

Comment: IsDigit will return true for all of these characters; other than 0-9 they won't be parsed as Integers through int.TryParse with default culture settings on an English machine - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm

Answer (score 25):

If you want just the pure `0-9` digits, use

```
if(a>='0' && a<='9')
```

`IsNumeric` and `IsDigit` both return true for some characters outside the 0-9 range:

[Difference between Char.IsDigit() and Char.IsNumber() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228532/difference-between-char-isdigit-and-char-isnumber-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6):

`Integer.TryParse` works well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: IsNumeric returns `true` for non-digit characters:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228532/difference-between-char-isdigit-and-char-isnumber-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about IsNumber, I wasn't aware of that. I'll remove that from my answer. Do you know if Integer.TryParse does the same thing for non-digit characters?

Comment: Never tried it, but with a US culture I suspect it would just consider `0-9`.

Answer (score 6):

The `bool Char.IsDigit(char c);` Method should work perfectly for this instance.

```
char a = '1';

if (Char.IsDigit(a))
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `System.Char.IsDigit` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Char.IsNumber`. Documentation and examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to just use a switch statement.  Something like:

```
switch(a)
{
  case '1':
    //do something.
    break;
  case '2':
    // do something else.
    break;
  default: // Not an integer
    throw new FormatException();
    break;
}
```

This will work as long as you're only looking for characters 0-9.  Anything more than that (say "10") would be a string and not a character.  If you're trying to just see if some input is an integer and the input is a string, you can do:

```
try
{
  Convert.ToInt32("10")
}
catch (FormatException err)
{
  // Not an integer, display some error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to check the first to characters of a string and **if the third character is numeric** and do it with **MyString.All(char.IsDigit)**:

```
if (cAdresse.Trim().ToUpper().Substring(0, 2) == "FZ" & cAdresse.Trim().ToUpper().Substring(2, 1).All(char.IsDigit))
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest answer:

```
char chr = '1';
char.isDigit(chr)
```