# Acess index of StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, function, methods, stringbuilder

I'm trying to convert the first index of a string to a int but I can't. Can someone explain how to access the index of a string and convert it to an int?

```
string a = "5"
public static bool VerificacaoNumero(string a, int[,] tabuleiro) 
{
  int b = a[0];
  return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no traces of `StringBuilder` in the post...

Comment: (Based on sample code you are looking for [how to check if the character is an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866214/how-to-check-if-the-character-is-an-integer) which looks like perfect duplicate to me).

Answer (score 2):

There is already a built-in .NET method to verify if a character is a digit: [Char.IsDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx)

```
string a = "5"
public static bool VerificacaoNumero(string a, int[,] tabuleiro) 
{
    return char.IsDigit(a[0]);
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this option far better. Totally forgot about IsDigit

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the string value to an int.

```
int b;
return int.TryParse(a[0], out b);
```

That should work for you.

Comment: TryParse does not take character... Clearly it should not work for anyone (except somehow for one person).