# how to check whether a number or letter has been entered in a textbox on KeyUp Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

On KeyPress or KeyUp event, how can I do something like this:

```
if (String.IsOnlyANumber(textBox.Text))
{ 
    do my things
}
else if(String.IsLettersAndEverythingElse(textBox.Text))
{
    do my other things
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: [how to check if the character is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866214/how-to-check-if-the-character-is-an-integer), [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/463299/8967612)

Comment: @41686d6564 why did you change the link? the last one was better

Comment: I didn't change the link. There are two links in my comment. The first post tells you how to check if a char is a digit and the second one tells you how to _get_ the char (in case you didn't know how) in the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: @41686d6564 sorry, my bad. Didn't saw it :D struggling hard in the mornings

Answer (score 0):

```
private void your_textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) 
    {
        // is a number
    }
    else 
    {
        // is anything else
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
textBox1.Text = string.Concat(textBox1.Text.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
```

in your KeyPress or KeyUp event.