# regular expression allow Latin letters and digitals number and disallow space

Tags: c#, regex

I have regular expression allow only latin letters and digitals number and disallow space. But this expression miss string where exist space. In my code I need see true and false. But I see true and true. How it fixed?

```cs
String str1="5asdfEDadgs2";
String str2 = "5 asdfgsadgs2";
String reg=@"^[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|.*$"

bool res = Regex.Match(str1,reg). Success; //Must show true
bool res2 = Regex.Match(str2, reg).Success; //Must show false

Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.WriteLine(res2);
```

Comment: You see `true` because it matches solely on the `.*`, meaning: every character (except newline chars) zero to unlimited times. If you insist on a regular expression you are almost there: use `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`. This matches on only one or more characters in the given ranges and will fail if any other character is encountered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing your regex to:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

You have in your current regex |.* this is effectively "or any charachter (including whitespace)"

Comment: or just `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need a Regex for that, you can simply use [`char.IsLetterOrDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a little bit of LINQ :

```
String str1="5asdfEDadgs2";
String str2 = "5 asdfgsadgs2";

bool res = str1.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit); //True
bool res2 = str2.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit); //False
```

You could also write the equivalent `str1.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))` but I find the method group form much cleaner.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't get "All" method.

Comment: @user2956406 Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file. If you have ReSharper you can also press ALT + ENTER, it will add the using directive automatically.

Comment: Never made this particular test, but: Regex should be way faster then Linq both generally and particularly speaking.

Comment: I think the OP meant letters and digits from the ASCII range. The (linked) documentation of `IsLetterOrDigit` states that _Valid letters and decimal digits are members of the following categories in UnicodeCategory: UppercaseLetter, LowercaseLetter, TitlecaseLetter, ModifierLetter, OtherLetter, or DecimalDigitNumber._ Checking the `DecimalDigitNumber` category shows that it contains _decimal digits or numbers_ from all sorts of languages/alphabets ... See also the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/228565/1809799 The regex given in the accepted answer should accomplish exactly that.