# How can I find the numbers in an array of characters?

Tags: c#

How can I find which characters in a `char[]` are numbers?

```
char[] example = { '2', 'a', '4', 'f', 'u', 'i', '6' };

if(example[3] == ???) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(example[3].toString());
}
```

Comment: English, Chinese, Indic, Arabic, Programmer?  Always thought that 'a' and 'f' were perfectly good numbers, that's how I learned to program :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So:

```
if (Char.IsDigit(example[3]))
{
   Console.WriteLine(...);
}
```

If you want all the chars:

```
IEnumerable<char> digitList = example.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c));
//or
char[] digitArray = example.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
```

Use Char.IsNumber if you want all the extra "numbers" in Unicode, specifically:

> Numbers include characters such as fractions, subscripts,
>   superscripts, Roman numerals, currency numerators, encircled numbers,
>   and script-specific digits.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply there is a method [`Char.IsNumber()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

with which you can test:

```
char[] example = { '2', 'a', '4', 'f', 'u', 'i', '6' };

if(Char.IsNumber(example[3]))

{

  Console.WriteLine(example[3].toString());

}
```

Comment: [The difference between Char.IsDigit() and Char.IsNumber()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228532/difference-between-char-isdigit-and-char-isnumber-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the numbers:

```
var numbers = example.Where(char.IsDigit);
```

If you want to check whether *specific* char is number or not:

```
if(char.IsDigit(example[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            char[] example = { '2', 'a', '4', 'f', 'u', 'i', '6' };

            if (char.IsDigit(example[3]))

            {

                Console.WriteLine(example[3]);

            }

        }
```